# implementing Singleton for xib, with initWithCoder and delegate

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, singleton, xib

so my problem is this:

I'm trying to have a singleton for a custom view xib. When I fire a notification it's not getting caught by the observer, because apparently my combobox has a different 'self' than '_sharedInstance'.

here is the code - ***initWithCoder***:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder{
   if (_sharedInstance){
       self = _sharedInstance;
       return self;
   }else{
       _sharedInstance = [super initWithCoder:coder];    
       return _sharedInstance;
   }
}
```

***awakeFromNib***: (because in initWithCoder: *_sharedInstance.cmbBox* is nil)

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    _sharedInstance.cmbBox.delegate = _sharedInstance;
}
```

The delegate that should catch the combobox selection:

```
// NSComboBoxDelegate:
-(void)comboBoxSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{
    if (notification.object == _sharedInstance.cmbBox){
         NSLog(@"Do Something!");
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DoSomething" object:_sharedInstance userInfo:nil];
    }
}
```

The problem is **notification.object != _sharedInstance.cmbBox**, so it never enters the if statement...

Did I do something stupid? :)

Comment: The pattern looks a bit strange. If you have your object (the one you calla  singleton) in the xib then it is already instantiated. Thus it is not possible to try and instantiate and set the _sharedInstance when you do. The only thing you need to provide a strong reference to it from the xib file owner - and you have your control-wide object. To try an do a true singleton for a custom view seems strange, do you really want a shared instance between multiple instances of the view if you choose to include 2 or more in the same project?

Comment: yes. that's the idea - sharing the same view in few multiple screens. 
how do I reference it to the same owner? if the xib is in different screens than it has different owners, no?

Comment: Your singleton can't have multiple comboboxes. What do you want to accomplish? A view you can use in multiple windows and set the delegate of all comboboxes to one delegate? In comboBoxSelectionDidChange, should all comboboxes do the same thing? Does the view have a viewcontroller?

Comment: no viewcontroller. I'm trying to make a common pannel for all screens - that if it's changes in one screen - it'd be changed on the other screen as well. therefor the delegate of all comboboxes is the same one.

Comment: Could you be missing the point of Model-View-Controller? — It sounds like your singleton object should be a data model. Your multiple views can each have their own view controllers, all referencing the data model for their content. This way, any changes made by one view, will be reflected in all of the other views. — (Unless, there's some special reason you wanted a singleton view that you haven't stated here.)